# How to execute commandline application (bat) before mercurial commit?

Tags: mercurial-hook

I would like to execute command line application before each commit (push) to central repository. If application will execute with errors, commit should fail with some message.

I have found some examples of python hooks, but nothing about calling bats or exe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just put the exe/batch file as the command for the hook (you probably dont need the bat and exe extensions):

```
[hooks]
pre-commit.example1 = /path/to/somebatfile.bat
pre-commit.example2 = /path/to/someexefile.exe
```